# How do I set Map value to an Array?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, protocol-buffers, grpc-web

I want make a grpc request. Request has a map field in proto file. I have generated js file for the protos using protoc. I am not able to define Map in the request.

```
var req_rg = new ResourceGroup();
req_rg.setResourcegroupname(payload.resourceGroupName);
req_rg.setResourcegroupid(payload.resourceGroupId);
req_rg.setTenantlinkid(TENANT_ID);
req_rg.getResourceoperationmapMap().set('resource', ['op1', 'op2'])
```

This is the .proto file for the message.

```
message ResourceGroup{

    string resourceGroupName = 1;
    string resourceGroupDescription = 2;
    map<string,SetOfString> resourceOperationMap = 3;
    string tenantLinkId = 4;
    map<string,string> attributes = 5;
    string resourceGroupId = 6;

}
```

I am getting this error.

```
TypeError: b.toArray is not a function
push../node_modules/google-protobuf/google-protobuf.js.jspb.Map.set
node_modules/google-protobuf/google-protobuf.js:4666
  4663 | 
  4664 | jspb.Map.prototype.set = function (a, b) {
  4665 |   var c = new jspb.Map.Entry_(a);
> 4666 |   this.valueCtor_ ? (c.valueWrapper = b, c.value = b.toArray()) : c.value = b;
  4667 |   this.map_[a.toString()] = c;
  4668 |   this.arrClean = !1;
  4669 |   return this;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you can set array as the value.
The definition looks like the map takes SetOfString as value.
You are supposed to set instance of SetOfString